# Google Cloud Run charges more CPU and RAM seconds than actually used

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have a Cloud Run Job running every 10min, on 1 vCPU and 2 GiB of RAM, with a 300sec timeout. There is no retry policy. The job always runs in less than 30 seconds, the average being around 20 seconds.

Based on these info, I was expecting to be using approximately:

- Minutes in a month: 31 * 24 * 60 ~= 45,000
- Runs per month: 45,000 / 10 = 4500
- Runtime per run: 20 seconds
- **Total expected vCPU-second usage**: 4500 * 20 = 90,000

Instead, the billing report indicates a number more than twice as high. Is there anything I am missing on? Where all this extra usage could come from?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TLDR: you get charged a minimum of 1 minute for each Job run.**

I realized that my actual usage was 179,176 vCPU-second for 3015 runs, corresponding to approximately a minute per run.

This sounded like a minimum time that would be billed for each run. It was confirmed by looking more in depth at the [pricing page](https://cloud.google.com/run/pricing) for Cloud Run.

It was NOT mentioned in the pricing table, but at the very bottom of the page: "Billable container instance time for Cloud Run jobs". I got fooled by the free tier, hopefully this will help others :)